# How do I interpret these mfcc graphs?

Tags: mfcc

[image]
[image]

The first graph represents mfcc plot for female and the second for male. How do I interpret this graph with colors. and what is that color scale on the right? How do I differentiate gender from these plots?

Comment: mfcc spectrograms, if you don't know what they represent then you should first read some theory.

Comment: Well, whatever a plot means necessarily needs to be part of the text that came with the plot, whatever this plot shows.

Comment: By the way, I mean that: if a student hands in a graph like this, it will get points deducted for unlabeled axes and unspecified units on the colorbar.

Comment: I think that the question the way it is posed, is too broad. Would it be possible for you to go through a similar technique such as the [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) and then come back and edit the question with any grey areas you may still have?